# t-test vs. comparing regression coefficients

Tags: regression, t-test

I understand that independent t-tests compare two means and establish whether they are statistically different from one another.

If I want to compare whether there are statistical differences in the coefficients from two linear regressions, what kind of test would I use? Is this also a t-test?

Comment: Yes, in general, but what kind of t-test it is depends on the data: do your regressions involve independent responses or not?

Comment: We can't answer this question unless you provide the information @whuber asked for.